# Присвоение разных классов элементам с одинаковым id на jQuery

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, ситуация следующая: есть два div с одинаковым id, они находятся в разных частях документа

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Мне необходимо добавить первому элементу класс `first`, а второму `second`
Чтобы в итоге получилась такая конструкция:

```
<div id="slider" class="first"></div>
<div id="slider" class="second"></div>
```

Как реализовать это на jQuery?

Comment: @Igor извините что не все знатоки jQuery. Приношу свои искреннейшие извинения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой `$('#slider')` селектор с одинаковым id на jQuery невозможно, вы получаете только первый элемент. Вот вам ЛайфХак `$('[id="slider"]')` ищет через тег.

```js
var obj = {
  0: "first",
  1: "second"
};
$.each($('[id="slider"]'), function(i) {
    $(this).addClass(obj[i]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Comment: звездочка в селекторе не обязательна id же точно совпадают

Comment: @Grundy спасибо убрал

Answer (score 2):

Свойство элемента `id` должно быть уникальным на странице. Вот [статья](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/id).
Либо сделайте разные ID этим элементам, либо вообще не используйте id и оставьте только классы.

```
<div class="slider first"></div>
<div class="slider second"></div>
```

Если вам нужно выбрать все `slider-элементы` используйте `$('.slider')`;
 Если какой-то конкретный слайдер `$('.slider.second')`
 Почитайте про [селекторы jQuery](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)